# How to select Bootstrap's collapsed menu button with CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, menu, background-color

I'm trying to select the default bootstrap collapsed menu button background color so whenever I hover or click, the background color changes, but haven't been able to find the class/id to select it via CSS

This is my website: davidliu.co - Resize the browser window so the menu button appears.

Comment: `.navbar-header > button {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default button hover effect is located in the bootstrap.min.css under:

`.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}`

You can either edit it there or you can override it by adding `#menu-button:hover {background-color:/*your color here*/;}` to your main.css file.